# Issue importing Selenium under Anaconda environment

Tags: python, selenium, anaconda

I am using Spyder through Anaconda platform for a webscraping project. I have tried to instantiate the Chrome driver as such.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
driver = Chrome()
```

But I do not get an answer from Chrome when I run the program. I have tried deleting and reinstalling the chrome driver.

Comment: _I am starting a new project and I do not know how to get selenium to work with Anaconda. I do not know which is the best platform for web automation. If anyone could help. Should I use Pycharm, Sublime Text or just Spyder on Anaconda._ Those are text editors/IDEs, what is your question? Have you installed the Selenium package with Conda?

Comment: Why are you editing this question after a year??? Why haven't you commented on whether the answer below works for you?

Comment: I don't need help with this question anymore. I was able to find the solution to it. I  am re-editing my questions because this is what stack overflow recommended to re-gain the ability to post questions once again.

Answer (score 0):

Find *Anaconda Prompt* from the start menu and type `conda install selenium` to install the selenium package. If you are using a separate environment, make sure you have activated the environment with `conda activate env` ('*env*': Your environment name) or simply specify the environment by `conda install -n env selenium`.